# Read SQS message posted by beanstalk daemon using a Python script

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to read SQS message that is posted by beanstalk daemon to my Python script. I know beanstalk posts message using HTTP post method. But how to read that message using a Python script. Please note, I'm not using any web framework.

Need a solution how to grab HTTP POST message in Python script without using any framework.

I tried a lot to search some references but failed.